# List specific data within a collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java

I have an Admin table that looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "userID1", "_class" : "com.test.Admin", "projectList" : 
[     {       "projectID" : "project1" }, 
      {       "projectID" : "project2" } 
] }
{ "_id" : "userID2", "_class" : "com.test.Admin", "projectList" : 
[     {       "projectID" : "project3" }, 
      {       "projectID" : "project4" } 
] }
```

I need a way to list all projects with in the Admin collection(i.e. fetch all "projectList" from each document)
How could I make one query,using java driver, to fetch all projectList that only has data!

The current approach I use is to fetch all admins.
Then write some java code to get all projects from each Admin.
However,I dislike my current approach.

Comment: Is your requirement that same as checking that `projectList` is not `null` ? You could use the aggregation framework here I believe however your approach might be best

Comment: You mean from perfomance wise,Java would be better to handle it better than Mongo. As if I was using SQL,it'd be better to make it over SQL Server instead !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate this to your Java driver:

```
db.admin.find({ projectList : {$exists : true}}, {projectList: 1})
```

It's checking that each the projectList property exists, and then using projection, only returns the projectList property for each matched document.

Probably something like (I've never used the Java driver):

```
query = new BasicDBObject("projectList", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));

cursor = find(query, BasicDBObject("projectList", 1);
```

Comment: I have tried:    DBCollection db = mongoOperations.getCollection("admin");
    BasicDBObject myQuery = new BasicDBObject("projectList", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)).append("projectList", 1);

    Object result = db.find(myQuery);

Comment: However it returns only one admin !

Comment: It returns a cursor. One at a time.